# Alembic migration: How to set server_onupdate in Alembic's alter_column function

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to change a table column in PostgreSQL using Alembic but I don't know how to perform the needed update to apply the SQLAlchemy's *server_onupdate* property.

The column is:

```
changed = Column(ArrowType(timezone=True), server_default=utcnow(), primary_key=True)
```

I'm using the Arrowtype column type from SQLAlchemy_utils package (this is not a problem).

My intention is to create something like this:

```
changed = Column(ArrowType(timezone=True), **server_onupdate=utcnow()**, primary_key=True)
```

But using the Alembic function: **alter_column**

In the documentation there are only references to the *server_default* property but nothing about *server_onupdate*

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I know this is old, but has anyone seen a good fix here? It's an open issue on GitHub related to SQLalchemy itself... https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4652

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Alembic doesn't provide logic for changing `server_onupdate` in `alter_column` see the [code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/blob/rel_1_9_4/alembic/operations/ops.py#L1599), however it provides logic for changing `server_default`. And there is the following trick for setting MySQL `ON UPDATE` in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#rendering-on-update-current-timestamp-for-mysql-mariadb-s-explicit-defaults-for-timestamp):

```
server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

So it's possible to achieve, if you'd change your column definition. But, if it looks too hack-ish, then it's always possible to write a direct SQL instruction in Alembic.

```
op.execute('ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN ....')
```

Update:

just noticed postgresql tag.. there is no `ON UPDATE` for columns in postgresql (only for foreign keys), so setting `server_onupdate` would do nothing. To get the same logic you'd need to make a db-side trigger or to use ORM-side `onupdate` or events.