# SQL Alchemy update time not working in Alembic revision

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a column in an alembic revision for update_time to show when the Column is updated.

Currently I have tried:

```py
sa.Column('update_time', sa.dialects.mysql.DATETIME(fsp=3), nullable=False, server_default=str(datetime.utcnow()), onupdate=str(datetime.utcnow()), server_onupdate=str(datetime.utcnow()))
```

I have also tried:

```py
sa.Column('test_time', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.func.now(), server_onupdate=sa.func.now(), onupdate=sa.func.now())
```

When the database is built is gets the utcnow() time fine as a DateTime.

However, when I update the column via the command line in mysql, the Column stays the same timestamp.

How do I get the timestamp to update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working with:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import TIMESTAMP

sa.Column('update_time', TIMESTAMP(), nullable=False, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```

Comment: for people trying this, there's a caveat, it might not work for all databases. at the time of writing, postgresql 15 doesn't support this. detail on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538105/1835157